# Unreasonable amount of "Files In Use" during WiX installation process

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I used WiX to build an installer (MSI) for an application, which works fine, except for this unreasonable amount of "applications that are using files that need to be updated by this setup":

[image: Excessive Files In Use during Installation]

This happens for some users some times, and I don't quite understand why this happens, and how to fix it.

I don't see a reason that the installation process of my application would conflict with all of these applications, and I'm not sure how to investigate it further.

My application is a standalone desktop application - not any add-on or something that interacts or depends on any of the applications listed.

The steps my installation process does:

1. Check that .Net framework 4.0 CP is available (exit if not).
2. Install the application under Program Files[Company][Product] (including my exe, my DLL, 2 third party DLL's that I bundle)
3. Install MS Visual C++ Runtime Redist 14.0 if needed
4. Add Start menu items for the application (launch & uninstall shortcuts)
5. Custom action for creating a scheduled task that starts my application on user logon as admin (the application runs in the tray as admin).
6. Custom action for starting the application after setup finishes (if checkbox is checked in last dialog).

Any advice on how to fix this, or at least investigate what causes this, will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it happen only when you run the installer and your desktop application is already running?

To investigate this further, best place to look at is your log file. The log file will have the details about the file which is being held by the other process, something like:

```
Info 1603. The file C:\...\abc.exe is being held in use by the following process: Name: xyz, Id: 19010, Window Title: 'xyz'. Close that application and retry.
Info 1603. The file C:\...\abc.dll is being held in use by the following process: Name: xyz123, Id: 9243, Window Title: 'xyz123'. Close that application and retry.
```

Once you determine the actual file being used by those other process, then it will help you figure out what the root cause is. Basically the [INSTALLVALIDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369546(v=vs.85).aspx) windows installer action determines if one or more files to be overwritten or removed are currently in use by an active process. An entry is added to an internal FilesInUse table if any file is overwritten or removed while it is open for execution or modification by any process during [File costing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368593(v=vs.85).aspx). The FilesInUse table contains columns for the name and full path of the file. When the InstallValidate action executes, the installer queries the FilesInUse table for entries and determines the name of the process using the file. The InstallValidate action adds one record to the ListBox user interface table for each unique process identified by this query.

Comment: thanks for all the details :-)
no, so far this has happened only during initial installation, before my application was installed or running.
could it be because of the MS Visual C++ Runtime merge module? could it be that my installer is replacing it, and all these applications are affected by it?
I'll try to look for clues in the logs of course - just throwing a guess :-)

Comment: Yup I think that's a well educated guess, C++ Runtime Redist could be the root cause.

Comment: So far no luck with reproducing the issue with logs enabled :-( In case C++ Runtime Redist is the root cause, what can I do to deal with it? I followed the WiX How-To on installing it (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html).

Comment: do you have redist already installed? if yes, remove it and try again.

Comment: tried removing the redist and running the installer multiple times, but it didn't trigger the issue... ended up dropping the dependency on it altogether...